# Validate maximum amount of images in input type html5

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I want to use an input type for uploading x amount of images. I want an alert to appear after the file Upload closes. I´m only using pure JavaScript for this.

I know I can use the option multiple for accepting multiple images.

```
<input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" multiple />
```

I know I can use the query selector for getting the amount of files.
I´m not sure which is the event I should be calling so the below code could run just after the file manager window closes.

```
amount = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files 
if (amount > 3){
  alert("Only 3 images are allowed!!!")
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');
var form = document.querySelector('#fileup');
input.onchange = function () {
    if (input.files.length > 3){
      alert("Only 3 images are allowed!!!");
      form.reset();
    }
};
```

```html
<form id="fileup">
<input type="file" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" multiple />
</form>
```